# Como transformar no R em gradual a geração de n número na distribuição normal

Tags: r

Desenvolvi um código para resolver a questão da imagem,que consiste em tentar aproximar a porcentagem de 68.2% números gerados na distribuição normal que estão entre -1 e 1. Segue o código:

```
x <- rnorm(100); x <- x[-1 <= x & x <= 1]
r1<-length(x)/100

y <- rnorm(1000); y <- y[-1 <= y & y <= 1]
r2<-length(y)/1000

z <- rnorm(10000); z <- z[-1 <= z & z <= 1]
r3<-length(z)/10000

print(r1*100)
print(r2*100)
print(r3*100)
```

Porém eu gostaria de transformar esse código em algo mais gradual,aonde seria gerado 100:1000000 dentro da distribuição normal e o valor em porcentagem fosse printado conforme o valor fosse crescendo gradualmente de 100 até 1000000. Para resolver esse problema pensei em criar um contador dentro da função while,porém não sei como ir aumentando o valor de números gerados dentro do parêntese gradualmente como se fosse um contador simples,preciso de uma luz nessa parte.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Veja bem, se você começar com o valor 100 e for aumentando gradualmente até 1000000 através de uma adição gradual, de 20 em 20 digamos, não chegará "nunca" a 1000000, pois são muitos passos. O que você precisa é de uma progressão geométrica, ou seja, um efeito multiplicativo. Você considera que multiplicar por 10 está muito rápido, e por isso gostaria de poder controlar o passo.

Então definamos seus limites inicial e final.

```
qt.inicial <- 100
qt.final <- 1000000
```

E também o número de passos desejado:

```
num.passos <- 20
```

Agora pense: eu devo multiplicar o número inicial (`qt.inicial`) um certo número de vezes (`num.passos`) por um certo fator, de forma a chegar ao número final (`qt.final`).
Ou seja, qt.inicial * fator ^ num.passos = qt.final.
Logo, para saber qual o fator desejado, basta recorrer à radiciação: fator = (qt.final / qt.inicial) ^ (1 / num.passos)

```
fator <- (qt.final / qt.inicial) ^ (1 / num.passos)
```

Então agora colocamos o resto de nossa lógica num loop:

```
for(i in 0:num.passos) {
  qt <- round(qt.inicial * fator ^ i, 0)
  x <- rnorm(qt); x <- x[-1 <= x & x <= 1]
  r <- length(x) / qt

  print(paste0("Para a quantidade = ", qt, " o resultado é: ", r*100))
}
```

Rodando este código, eu obtive a seguinte saída:

```
[1] "Para a quantidade = 100 o resultado é: 65"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 158 o resultado é: 64.5569620253165"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 251 o resultado é: 75.2988047808765"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 398 o resultado é: 66.0804020100502"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 631 o resultado é: 68.1458003169572"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 1000 o resultado é: 67.9"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 1585 o resultado é: 66.4984227129338"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 2512 o resultado é: 68.6305732484076"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 3981 o resultado é: 69.304194925898"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 6310 o resultado é: 68.4310618066561"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 10000 o resultado é: 67.7"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 15849 o resultado é: 68.3197678086946"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 25119 o resultado é: 68.3466698515068"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 39811 o resultado é: 68.4584662530456"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 63096 o resultado é: 68.4718524153671"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 1e+05 o resultado é: 68.415"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 158489 o resultado é: 68.2924366990769"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 251189 o resultado é: 68.2764770750312"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 398107 o resultado é: 68.1969922658984"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 630957 o resultado é: 68.3056056117929"
[1] "Para a quantidade = 1e+06 o resultado é: 68.219"
```

Ajustando o valor da variável `num.passos`, você pode obter a gradação que preferir.

Comment: Muito obrigado,realmente o que eu tinha tentando idealizar! Agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a ideia do 'user2332849' e plotando para observarmos a convergência.

```
qt.inicial <- 10000
qt.final <- 1000000
num.passos <- 2000
n <- round(seq(qt.inicial, qt.final, length.out = num.passos))
ex <- c()

for(i in 1:num.passos) {
  x <- rnorm(n[i]); x <- x[-1 <= x & x <= 1]
  r <- length(x) / n[i] * 100
  ex <- c(ex, r)
}

mean(ex) # [1] 68.27124
plot(ex)
```

- tomei a liberdade de modificar o código para facilitar a interpretação.

[image: Plot da convergência]